# OpenVPN tunnel not able to support secure connect request

Tags: openvpn, tunneling, tap, tun

In CentOS 7 host we have installed openvpn package and did create an tunnel using OpenVPN tunneling for eth9 and tap9.
Everthing work fine for unsecure connection but when we try to connect to server on secure port i.e. 443 or so using openssl we are getting error as below

```
openssl>s_client -connect 192.168.10.2:443
"error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:"
```

It seems to be some issue the way tunnel is configured as we are not using any server.conf or client.conf for openvpn.
The script which we use for creating tunnel is given below

```
#!/bin/bash

#################################
# Set up Ethernet bridge on Linux
# Requires: bridge-utils
#################################

# Define Bridge Interface
br="br0"

# Define list of TAP interfaces to be bridged,
# for example tap="tap0 tap1 tap2".
tap="tap0"

# Define physical ethernet interface to be bridged
# with TAP interface(s) above.
eth="eth0"
eth_ip="192.168.8.4"
eth_netmask="255.255.255.0"
eth_broadcast="192.168.8.255"

for t in $tap; do
    openvpn --mktun --dev $t
done

brctl addbr $br
brctl addif $br $eth

for t in $tap; do
    brctl addif $br $t
done

for t in $tap; do
    ifconfig $t 0.0.0.0 promisc up
done

ifconfig $eth 0.0.0.0 promisc up

ifconfig $br $eth_ip netmask $eth_netmask broadcast $eth_broadcast
```

So any thoughts how to fix this issue.

Comment: The default port is 1194 - have you specified port 443 in your server's openvpn configuration?

Comment: Actually I have not setup any server.conf as we are bridging the stuff for QEMU machines. So do we need to set server.conf properly for going for a secure connection?

Comment: I think what I'm hearing is that OpenVPN is in fact not configured and not in use at all...